# Как передать сообщения из Telegram на сервер?

Tags: telegram

Возможно ли реализовать передачу всех новых сообщений ( людей, каналов, чатов) из телеграм аккаунта на сервер? Например я подписан на канал и все новые посты канала сразу же могу читать на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Да, нужно добавить своего бота в чат/канал и настроить ему callback.
Тогда при каждом новом сообщении будет дёргаться Ваш url для callback'a.

Comment: Проблема в том что как раз бота нельзя подписать на чужой канал.

Comment: Этот никак нельзя обойти. Бот сам не может начать беседу/подписаться на канал или что-то в этом роде.